# C Program - Output is shown at next line without using newline character

Tags: c, output, newline

In this code after typing all the user input when asked the code has to give output for same.

This is the part of the code given below where it prints the output but after the output for `city_1[i].city` is printed the further output is printed on newline.

In the `printf` statement I didn't used `"\n"` after `"%s"`.

```
for (i = 0; i <= k - 1; i++) {
    printf("   %s      %d      %f%", city_1[i].city, city_1[i].p, city_1[i].l);
    //printf("\n");
}
```

I'm using *Visual Studio 2015* for debugging my code.

Can anyone help and explain me in this issue?

Given below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <process.h>

//GLOBAL-VARIABLE DECLARTION
#define MAX 1000

//GLOBAL-STRUCTURES DECLARATION
struct census {
    char city[MAX];
    long int p;
    float l;
};

//GLOBAL-STRUCTURE-VARIABLE DECLARATION
struct census cen[MAX] = { 0 };

//USER-DEFINED FUNCTION
struct census sortm_city(struct census city_1[]);
struct census sortm_population(struct census popu[]);
struct census sortm_literacy(struct census lite[]);
void header();

void header() {
    printf("*-*-*-*-*CENSUS_INFO*-*-*-*-*");
    printf("\n\n");
}

//PROGRAM STARTS HERE
main() {    
    //VARIABLE-DECLARATION
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0;
    char line[MAX] = { 0 };
    char o = { 0 };

    //FUNCTION CALL-OUT
    header();

    printf("Enter No. of City : ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf_s(line, "%d", &j);

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Enter Name of City, Population and Literacy level");
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= j - 1; i++) {
        printf("City No. %d - Info :", i + 1);
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("City Name : ");
        fgets(cen[i].city, MAX, stdin);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Population : ");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        sscanf_s(line, "%d", &cen[i].p);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Literacy : ");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        sscanf_s(line, "%f", &cen[i].l);
        printf("\n");

        printf("_____________________________________");
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* ");
    printf("Census Information");
    printf(" *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= j - 1; i++) {
        printf("City No. %d - Info :", i + 1);
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("City Name : %s", cen[i].city);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Population : %d", cen[i].p);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Literacy : %0.2f", cen[i].l);
        printf("\n");

        printf("_____________________________________");
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("Enter one option from the following : \n\n");
    printf("(a) To Sort the List Alphabetically. \n");
    printf("(b) To Sort the List based on Literacy Level. \n");
    printf("(c) To Sort the List based on Population. \n\n");
    printf("Please type a proper option. \n");

    n = 0;

    while (n == 0) {
        scanf_s(" %c", &o);

        switch (o) {
          case 'a':
            sortm_city(cen, j);
            n = 1;
            break;

          case 'b':
            sortm_population(cen);
            n = 1;
            break;

          case 'c':
            sortm_literacy(cen);
            n = 1;
            break;

          default:
            printf("Option INVALID \n");
            printf("Please type a proper option. \n");
            n = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    //TERMINAL-PAUSE
    system("pause");
}

struct census sortm_city(struct census city_1[], int k) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    //FOR TRANSFERRING
    float b = 0;
    int s = 0;
    char line_0[MAX] = { 0 };

    for (i = 1; i <= k - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= k - 1; j++) {
            if (strcmp(city_1[j - 1].city, city_1[j].city) > 0) {
                //SORTING THE LIST ALPHABETICALLY.
                strcpy(line_0, city_1[j - 1].city);
                strcpy(city_1[j - 1].city, city_1[j].city);
                strcpy(city_1[j].city, line_0);

                //COPYING POPULATION AND LITERACY TO RIGHT PLACE.

                //POPULATION :
                s = city_1[j - 1].p;
                city_1[j - 1].p = city_1[j].p;
                city_1[j].p = s;

                //LITERACY : 
                b = city_1[j - 1].l;
                city_1[j - 1].l = city_1[j].l;
                city_1[j].l = b;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* ");
    printf("Sorted list in Alphabetical Order");
    printf(" *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("___________________________________________________\n");
    printf("|   *City Name*   |   Population   |   Literacy   | \n");

    for (i = 0; i <= k - 1; i++) {
        printf("   %s      %d      %f%", city_1[i].city, city_1[i].p, city_1[i].l);
        //printf("\n");
    }
}

struct census sortm_population(struct census popu[]) {
    printf("-------");
}

struct census sortm_literacy(struct census lite[]) {
    printf("-------");
}
```

Comment: Add something visible around the `%s` for the city name, such as square brackets, and you will see that the hard return is "inside" its name. Duplicate of 1,000 "`fgets` includes a newline" questions.

Comment: You are using deprecated old-style declarators; a standard compliant compiler will warn. Use correct prototypes for your functions! And: TL;DR. Provide a [mcve] (focus on the first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the linefeed that `fgets()` leaves at the end of the line it read from the stream. If the buffer is too short or if the last line in the file does not end with a line terminator, the buffer will not end with a `\n` before the final `\0`, in all other cases, it will.

A simple way to remove the linefeed if present is:

```
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
```

It overwrites the `\n` if it finds one, otherwise it overwrites the `\0` with a `\0`.

Note that you should test the return value of `fgets()`, it returns `NULL` if it fails to read a line at end of file.

Note also that it is simpler and more idiomatic to write your `for` loops this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) { ... }
```

The index `0` will be included and index `j` won't be, which does the same as your syntax, but with a simpler more readable way.

You could also use `qsort` to sort your table with 3 different comparison functions.

Also note that your definition of `main()` is obsolete and incorrect for C99 and later C Standards.  You should either write `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Here is a list of the issues:

- You define census member `p` as `long int` but use `%d` to read it via `sscanf` and print it with `printf`, the proper format is `%ld`.
- You define the sortm_xxx functions as returning a `struct census`, this is incorrect, and `sortm_city` indeed returns nothing, they should be defined as `void`.
- `header` should be declared and defined as `void header(void)`
- `main` should be defined as `int main(void)`
- you use `scanf_s` and `sscanf_s`.  These functions are probably recommended by Visual Studio, but they are not always available on other systems, `scanf` and `sscanf` are and can be used safely with some precautions, especially for the `%s` and `%[` formats, which you do not use here anyway.
- `fgets` leaves the `\n` at the end of the line.  You should check the retuen value to detect premature end of file and strip the `\n`.  I defined a utility function `xgets()` that does both.  `strcspn()` returns the number of characters from its string argument that are not among the list given as a second string argument.
- The printing code uses `%f` for the literacy level, resulting in 6 decimal places (the default), you should use `%7.2f` to get 2 decimal places and align the column contents.
- You must use `%%` to print a `%` character with `printf`.
- I added some alignment arguments in your `printf` format string to align the output, assuming a fixed width font: `"| %-15s |   %10ld   |   %7.2f%%   |"`. `%-15s` pads the city name to 15 characters with spaces after the city name, `%10ld` pads the population to 10 characters with spaces **before** the population figure. `%7.2f` produces 2 decimal places and pads with spaces before the literacy figure upto 7 characters before the `.`.
- I used `qsort` and defined 3 comparison functions for the 3 sort options.
- I moved the code for printing the census data to a separate function.  Is is better to factorize code this way to write less code and avoid inconsistencies when you later fix bugs.

Here is the corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//GLOBAL-VARIABLE DECLARTION
#define MAX 1000

//GLOBAL-STRUCTURES DECLARATION
struct census {
    char city[MAX];
    long int p;
    float l;
};

//GLOBAL-STRUCTURE-VARIABLE DECLARATION
struct census cen[MAX] = { 0 };

//USER-DEFINED FUNCTION
void header(void);
void sortm_city(struct census cp[], int n);
void sortm_population(struct census cp[], int n);
void sortm_literacy(struct census cp[], int n);
void print_census(struct census cp[], int k, const char *legend);

void header(void) {
    printf("*-*-*-*-*CENSUS_INFO*-*-*-*-*");
    printf("\n\n");
}

char *xgets(char *dest, int size, FILE *fp) {
    /* read a line from the user */
    if (!fgets(dest, size, fp)) {
        /* read failed, end of file detected */
        printf("Premature end of file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* strip the \n if present */
    dest[strcspn(dest, "\n")] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

//PROGRAM STARTS HERE
int main(void) {
    //VARIABLE-DECLARATION
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0;
    char line[MAX] = { 0 };
    char o = { 0 };

    //FUNCTION CALL-OUT
    header();

    printf("Enter No. of City : ");
    xgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &j) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Enter Name of City, Population and Literacy level");
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("City No. %d - Info :", i + 1);
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("City Name : ");
        xgets(cen[i].city, MAX, stdin);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Population : ");
        xgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        sscanf(line, "%ld", &cen[i].p);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Literacy : ");
        xgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        sscanf(line, "%f", &cen[i].l);
        printf("\n");

        printf("_____________________________________");
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* ");
    printf("Census Information");
    printf(" *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("City No. %d - Info :", i + 1);
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("City Name : %s", cen[i].city);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Population : %ld", cen[i].p);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Literacy : %0.2f", cen[i].l);
        printf("\n");

        printf("_____________________________________");
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("Enter one option from the following : \n\n");
    printf("(a) To Sort the List Alphabetically. \n");
    printf("(b) To Sort the List based on Literacy Level. \n");
    printf("(c) To Sort the List based on Population. \n\n");
    printf("Please type a proper option. \n");

    n = 0;
    while (n == 0) {
        scanf(" %c", &o);

        switch (o) {
        case 'a':
            sortm_city(cen, j);
            n = 1;
            break;

        case 'b':
            sortm_population(cen, j);
            n = 1;
            break;

        case 'c':
            sortm_literacy(cen, j);
            n = 1;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Option INVALID \n");
            printf("Please type a proper option. \n");
            n = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    //TERMINAL-PAUSE
    system("pause");
}

void print_census(struct census cp[], int k, const char *legend) {
    int i;

    printf("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- %s *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*", legend);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("___________________________________________________\n");
    printf("|    City Name    |   Population   |   Literacy   |\n");
    printf("___________________________________________________\n");

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf("| %-15s |   %10ld   |   %7.2f%%   |", cp[i].city, cp[i].p, cp[i].l);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("___________________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n\n");
}

int compare_census_city(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct census *ca = a;
    const struct census *cb = b;
    return strcmp(ca->city, cb->city);
}

int compare_census_population(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct census *ca = a;
    const struct census *cb = b;
    if (ca->p > cb->p)
        return -1;
    if (ca->p < cb->p)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int compare_census_literacy(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct census *ca = a;
    const struct census *cb = b;
    if (ca->l > cb->l)
        return -1;
    if (ca->l < cb->l)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void sortm_city(struct census cp[], int n) {
    qsort(cp, n, sizeof(struct census), compare_census_city);
    print_census(cp, n, "Sorted list in Alphabetical Order");
}

void sortm_population(struct census cp[], int n) {
    qsort(cp, n, sizeof(struct census), compare_census_population);
    print_census(cp, n, "Sorted list by decreasing Popupation");
}

void sortm_literacy(struct census cp[], int n) {
    qsort(cp, n, sizeof(struct census), compare_census_literacy);
    print_census(cp, n, "Sorted list in decreasing Literacy level");
}
```

Comment: Man I am new in C. I didn't understood how to use line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; in my code. Can you please modify the part of my code?

I tried different ways to remove newline character but it's not working.

Thanks for reply :)

Comment: @Eddy: I added more remarks and a modified version of the code.  Try it out, study it, you have good basic skills and can progress rapidly.

Comment: Thanks alot for adding remarks and modifying my code. As I told you before I'm new in C. The next chapter I'm going to read is pointer so I don't know much about it. But I studied the code and understood most of it. I got few questions to ask - 1) Why there is a '!' sign before fgets in xgets function? - 2) Can't we just use fgets without if statement? - 3) I understood the way arguments are called in qsort but didn't understood how qsort function is actually working. I can't understand what exactly is it doing when the qsort function is called?

Answer (score 5):

`fgets` includes the `\n` character that the user typed into the returned string. So, when you print that string, you get a new line.